# Unpacking a tar.gz file with symlinks into another directory

Tags: macos, unix, tar

I have a directory on a Unix server that contains many subdirectories and many symlinks that point to subdirectories. If I display the contents with ls -la, the following path is displayed, for example.

/customers/41/websites/cms

I have packed the directory cms with all subdirectories and symlinks.

Now I want to discover everything on my Mac. However, into another basic directory, as I cannot create the following directory because of the rights:
/clients/41/websites/cms

I have created a directory on my Mac:
~/development/www/mycompany/clients/41/websites/cms

Everything should be unpacked there with working symlinks.

How can I realise this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [tardy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tardy/) to transform the tar ball file.

Or write your C program using [`#include <tar.h>`](https://www.mankier.com/0p/tar.h)

See also [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) (or compile it then improve it on your MacOSX system)